# Some programs install twince in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, 20.04

I did a clean reinstall of Ubuntu this morning, came from 18.04 and am now using 20.04. So once Ubuntu successfully installs I naturally go ahead and begin installing programs. The Ubuntu Software interface and icons wouldn't load properly and would give me strange '*Unable to install “blender”: snap “blender” has “install-snap” change in progress*', so I just used the terminal.

After installing a few programs via `sudo apt install` I realize that I have two copies of some (blender, krita, obs-studio) and only one expected copy of others (inkscape, scribus). So I use `sudo apt remove blender` to try and uninstall them but only one copy is removed. After searching around in my files and see that I have a snap folder even though I never installed via `snap`, so I `sudo snap remove blender` and it removes the second copy. How come do I have a snap folder if I install via `apt` ? Why do I get two copies of programs when I do a regular `apt install` ?

Has anyone else had this issue ?

Comment: You can have more than two copies installed; you can have a *deb* package installed, plus multiple versions of *snap* packages installed from varying channels. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Software will install *snaps* and *deb* packages.

Comment: Ubuntu Software is now an interface for snap-store in 20.04. It installs snap versions by default if it is available in snap. If you don't want snap and don't like the terminal, then install `synaptic` from terminal using `sudo apt install synaptic`.

Comment: Ok I can understand that for some reason 20.04 installs both _deb_ and _snap_ but now how can I disable that ? I don't have a need for multiple versions of the same program. And its cluttering up my application launcher screen with all those duplicates...